# get the url connection as String in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request, response

I have to call a url from my jsp to get an xml file. The problem I have is I have to be logged to get this page.

I need to open www.myServer.com/file.xml

I tried with URLConnection and current cookies, but it doesnt work because the cookie is for the client (client.com) and the urlConnection is opened from the server(myServer.com), they don't match and the Authentication fails.

I also try with

```
response.sendRedirect(www.myServer.com/file.xml);
```

wich acepts the loggin but opens the file in the browser, I need to get the contents of file.xml in my jsp to read the data it contents.

How can I do this?